# Restricting access to all routes but one

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I'm starting to experiment with ExpressJS + AngularJS and I've run into a stressful situation.

My goal is to have one login page and one dashboard page, and using Passport + MongoDB I'll authenticate a user in and, if credentials are correct, redirect him to the dashboard page.

I've started with the [angular-express-seed](https://github.com/btford/angular-express-seed) and modified it so I ended up with the previously mentioned views:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/login',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    }).
    when('/dashboard', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard',
      controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/login'
    });
```

I'm serving each partial view with:

```
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);


exports.partials = function (req, res) {
  var name = req.params.name;
  res.render('partials/' + name);
};
```

The login system is working correctly except for the part that I can access the dashboard directly (without loging in at all).

So I guess I need to figure out if the user if authenticated, before granting him access to the dashboard (or any other area for that matter).

I found this that does the trick:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

and I would call it on every `GET` to a partial

```
app.get('/partials/:name', ensureAuthenticated, routes.partials);
```

The big problem here is that the login view is also a partial, and I don't want `ensureAuthenticated` to run when that's the view being requested.

Currently calling `ensureAuthenticated` on every partial request crashes any browser, no errors whatsoever.

**What I've tried so far (and did not work):**

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
      if ( req.route.params.name !== 'login' && req.isAuthenticated() ) { return next(); }
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
```

Also tried calling the login view with its own `app.GET` and not using `ensureAuthenticated` but somehow Angular flips off and does not even load.

Any ideas on how to resolve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me if the first (unmodified) version of `ensureAuthenticated` crashes your browsers, or the last version (in which you check for `/partials/login`), although no matter what, it shouldn't happen (if by 'crashing' you mean 'stalls', that's a tell-tale sign of Express not sending back a response)

But as an alternative, try this:

```
app.get('/partials/login', routes.partials);
app.get('/partials/:name', ensureAuthenticated, routes.partials);
```

Your `routes.partials` does have to check explicitly if it's called for the login route, because in that case the `name` parameter won't exist in `req.params`.

Just to make sure: do you have a server-side handler for `/login` as well? Otherwise the `res.redirect('/login')` isn't going to work.

Comment: adding app.get('/partials/login', routes.partials); and making the name parameter check worked. Still i have a problem, i'm loggin in and going to my dashboard, then i'm cleaning the session cookie and refreshing to see if it redirects to /login. It does show the login view but the url still says its on /dashboard, any idea why ?

Comment: Ok so it's showing the login view because i've returned it on my /login handler. Shouldn't res.redirect('/login'); redirect ? instead its going to my app.get('/login', routes.login); and returning res.render('partials/login');

Comment: @mfreitas the redirect is send during an AJAX call, because Angular is  requesting the partial. So the AJAX call is redirected, not your main page url.

Comment: yes, i'm just missing that part.. how would i redirect to the application root "/" ?

Comment: @mfreitas I don't think there's an easy way to do that during loading of a template. You could use [resolve](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider) on your dashboard route to make a call to the server to check if the user is logged in before the route is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that server side redirecting on XHR request is a good practice. XHR request should return 401 if the user is not authorized and the client side (Angular) should take the action as displaying notification message and redirecting user to the login partial. Look at [this project](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) for handling such requests. There are [demo](http://witoldsz.github.io/angular-http-auth/) and [blog post](http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application).